# Passing a variable to the template.php file in FuelPHP Framework

Tags: php, fuelphp

I am really new to FuelPHP and PHP / frameworks in general and managed to get everything setup and some controllers running etc. However I am not sure how I can pass a variable I set to the template.php file.

app/views/template.php

Part in question:

```
<body class="<?php echo $bodyClass; ?>">
```

app/classes/controller/dashboard.php

```
class Controller_Dashboard extends Controller_Template
{

    /**
     * The basic welcome message
     *
     * @access  public
     * @return  Response
     */
    public function action_index()
    {
        return Response::forge(View::forge('dashboard/index'));
    }

    /**
     * The 404 action for the application.
     *
     * @access  public
     * @return  Response
     */
    public function action_404()
    {
        return Response::forge(Presenter::forge('dashboard/404'), 404);
    }
}
```

app/classes/view/dashboard/index.php

```
class View_Dashboard_Index extends ViewModel
{
    /**
     * Prepare the view data, keeping this in here helps clean up
     * the controller.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function view()
    {
        $this->template = $this->request()->param('bodyClass', '');
    }
}
```

I am sure im getting it wrong, well clearly i am as its not working and i get:

```
Fuel\Core\PhpErrorException [ Notice ]:
Undefined variable: bodyClass

C:/Websites/Annilla/Clients/Four04 Packaging/DEV/NEW/BUILD/backend/app/views/template.php @ line 24
```

Any ideas?

Also one another thing, is it possible to add partials like loading in menus, headers, footers etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another property inside:

```
$this->template->bodyClass = 'container'; // just assign
```

And yes, you can add other properties as well.

Comment: I add that in the view or the controller? thanks for your help btw

Comment: @James i usually add it in the controller thats being extended from `Controller_Template`, so in your case add it inside `Controller_Dashboard`

Comment: @James here are examples http://fuelphp.com/docs/general/controllers/template.html thats the same thing i do, declare the template file on the properties of the class, then assign `$this->template->whatever` when needed

Comment: Cool i gave it a go which worked on login page, which i set a different template but when it logs in just shows <p>testing</p> and not using default template so trying to work that out so i can see it working lol

Comment: @James yes, of course different template, then different properties, if they share the same template, then it will be used across all views, glad this helped

Comment: Well i managed to use login template when on login and setting the class so all good! its also using the login.php template but when login i redirect to dashboard/ but just shows the view content which is <p>test</p> and not using any wrapper template any ideas? shall send some code details for you to check? if thats ok? 12:20pm and need to crack for when i get into office to demo lol

Comment: was taken on as frontend and they thought backend was just doing a database so im having to fill the whole doing the backend lol

Comment: @James take note that of course using template properties, they need to share the same template, if you're not using the login template inside the dashboard, then of course you can't use it, if you want to share some info, might as well use sessions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117262/discussion-between-james-and-ghost).